# Node.js: Does Anyone Have a Non-trivial node-soap Client Example?

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl, node-soap

I'm asking this question just so I can answer it.

Here's a second, dummy line so that the question-that's-not-really-a-question makes it past the auto-filter.

Answer (score 1):

After three working days, I finally got node-soap to work properly. I've found that when working with Node.js, it's frequently difficult to find a good, solid, real-world example. After dozens of web searches, many trivial examples, lots of blog posts and the like, here's the example that I needed; maybe it'll help someone else.

I need to call the GetValuesForNamedID function of a remote SOAP service, and to do that I need my SOAP message to look like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:APIAccessRequestHeader xmlns:h="urn:messages.ws.company.com/v1_4">
            <Token/>
        </h:APIAccessRequestHeader>
        <h:ClientInfoHeader xmlns:h="urn:messages.ws.company.com/v1_4" xmlns="urn:messages.ws.company.com/v1_4">
            <AppID>Helpful Example</AppID>
        </h:ClientInfoHeader>
        <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:UsernameToken>
                <o:Username>adminuser</o:Username>
                <o:Password>adminpass</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <GetValuesForNamedID xmlns="urn:messages.ws.company.com/v1_4">
            <FieldName>Contact.Emails.Emaillist.Addresstype</FieldName>
        </GetValuesForNamedID>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

There's a lot going on here: there's a header and a body and namespacing and authentication. I can do this blindfolded in .NET with C#, but I'm less experienced with Node.js. I'm going to leave all of the "installing node-soap with npm" stuff to you - that's all pretty straightforward. I'm also just going to give you a JS function that does the thing and strip away all the extraneous bits of my project that aren't germane. Read the comments for the walk-through.

```
const soap = require('soap');

const wsdl = 'https://somesite.com/path/to?wsdl'

soap.createClient(wsdl, function(err, client) {
  // arg will get passed to the function call once we finally get to that point: the tag name in
  // the generated SOAP will be "FieldName" and it will have the value "Contact.Emails..."
  var arg = {FieldName: 'Contact.Emails.Emaillist.Addresstype'}

  // There are two SOAP header variables here. The reason I needed two is because they require
  // different namespacing. We'll come back to that in a second.
  var soapHeader1 = {
    // This SOAP header will end up containing two elements...

    // This is the first one, which creates the <APIAccessRequestHeader> element. It will have
    // a <Token> element that's empty. (Why? The peculiarities of the service. Don't worry about
    // it.)
    APIAccessRequestHeader: {
      Token : {}
    },
    // This is the second one, which creates the <ClientInfoHeader> element. It will have an
    // <AppID> element with the value shown.
    ClientInfoHeader : {
      AppID : 'Helpful Example'
    },
  }

  // Here's the second SOAP header, used for security. It'll generate an XML snippet that looks
  // something like
  // <Security>
  //   <UsernameToken>
  //     <Username>adminuser</Username>
  //     <Password>adminpass</Password>
  //   </UsernameToken>
  // </Security>
  // There'll be some namespacing and other dirt, but that's the basic idea.
  var soapHeader2 = {
    Security : {
      UsernameToken : {
        Username : 'adminuser',
        Password : 'adminpass'
      }
    }
  }

  // Adding the SOAP headers. This is the step that sets the namespacing we need. I'm not sure why
  // the second parameter is null, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The third parameter is the
  // tag prefix (e.g. <o:Security> and <h:ClientInfoHeader>) and the fourth parameter is the URL
  // that makes each prefix meaningful.
  client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader1, null, 'h', 'urn:messages.ws.company.com/v1_4')
  client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader2, null, 'o', 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd');

  // Now we can finally call the GetValuesForNamedID function that the service exposes
  client.GetValuesForNamedID(arg, function(err, result, rawResponse, soapHeader, rawRequest) {
    // TODO: useful stuff
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you please share example based on below WSDL.

Comment: https://docs.mendix.com/apidocs-mxsdk/apidocs/attachments/9535497/19398865.wsdl